# Ruby on Rails: how to link employees table with devise authentification

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model "Employee", some employees have access to the site via device authentication. What's the best solution to combine it?
I need such functions:

1) Click a button in index view of employees to create login

2) If login exists - two buttons will display - change and delete access. Change action should change login and pass

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Is your "Employees" table the one already linked to the current Devise authentication or is it separate as of now ?

Answer (score 0):

Devise gem ships with a method called authenticate_user! which can be used to "secure" a controller action.
So in your case, I would say that you could do something like the following. 
There is the nice helper provided by the **gem devise** current_user which returns the currently logged in user.
I could imagine something in your view logic like

```
#index.html.erb
#your code
<% if current_user.admin? %>
#the code for your buttons
<% else %>
#your code
<% end %>
```

Keep in mind that you can specify other controller actions e.g "only: [:create, :destroy]

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
before_filter authenticate_user!, only: [:create]
##The rest of your controller
```

You may also check the gems Ability or Cancan if you want to manage permissions.
Hope this helps.